# Rails search functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am taking a rails class at my University and I am trying to create a search form which will show the results on the same page rather than show a different page of results. Is this something simple to do? I am creating a museum app with artifacts for each museum but I want the user to search artifacts from either page.

On my routes.rb I have

```
resources :artifacts do
    collection do
        get 'search'
    end
  end
```

On my museum index I have the code below that he gave us but not sure how to tweak the get routes for the same page.

```
<%= form_tag search_artifacts_path, :method => 'get' do %>

    <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_text, params[:search_text] %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
    </p>

<% end %>

<% if @artifacts %>
    <p> <%= @artifacts.length %> matching artifacts. </p>

    <h2> Matching Artifacts </h2>
    <% @artifacts.each do |a| %>

        <%= link_to "#{a.name} (#{a.year})", a %><br />

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is easy. Just have the index page return the search results if `params[:search_text]` is present - this way you don't need a new route or a different page.

```
class ArtifactsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @artifacts = Artifact.search(params[:search_text])
  end    
end

class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(query)
    if query
      where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{query}%")
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

So then your form looks like:

```
<%= form_tag artifacts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
   <%= text_field_tag :search_text, params[:search_text] %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

So what you really want to do is any page you want to search, include a form which makes a request to that same page.

Then in each of those controller methods just put this line of code:

```
    @artifacts = Artifact.search(params[:search_text])
```

and that will populate the `@artifcats` array with only artifacts that match the search query.

Comment: I entered the first portion in the artifacts controller and the def self.search portion in the artifact.rb. But I get this error when I type in a keyword. "SQLite3::SQLException: near "ILIKE": syntax error: SELECT "artifacts".* FROM "artifacts"  WHERE (name ILIKE '%u-505%')"

Comment: Ah, your using SQLite, the SQL command should then be 'LIKE' instead of 'ILIKE'.  'ILIKE' is Postgresql only.

Comment: Ok no error but now instead of showing on the same page it sends me to the artifacts page instead of staying on the museums page I was on.

Comment: So you are submitting the search form on the museum show page and you want to redirect back there?

Comment: Yea I would like which ever page the user is on to be able to search for for artifacts but show on the results on that page they were on instead of going to a new one. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: @TheDelChop , if I wanted to add more than one column from the database, how would I do that? So currently it is just name: how would I add another? I tried  where('name LIKE ? or date LIKE ?', "%#{query}%") but the error is wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2). Thanks for posting though this has been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Ransack" gem. It can also perform some more powerful searches.