# Search functionality result should be in the same page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search

I have view which contains a search form like below:

```
 <div>
  <%= form_tag :action => 'search' do %>
   <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => 'nil' %>
   </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

whenever i am clicking search button it is calling a new view which i dont want.
I want to be in the same page to do some action and display the result there only.
Can any one direct me how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489733/rails-search-functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from the following blog

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

Answer (score 0):

if your search form is in index.html.erb and you want the search result on the same page then

**in your controller**

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    # search query
  else
    # listing records
  end
end
```

**in view**
replace `<%= form_tag :action => 'search', :method => :get do %>`

with `<%= form_tag :action => 'index' do %>`